# Parameters for render method in Backbone View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine, backbone-views

I'm using this coffeescript code:

in a spec file:

```
index = new MeetingIndex(render: false, collection: booking.meetings)
index.render(writeTo: '.sandbox')
```

in the view file:

```
render: (options = {}) ->
  console.log 'options'
  console.log options
  console.log 'options'
  options[key] ||= val for key, val of writeTo: 'body', enhanceUI: true
```

the browser console prints:

```
Object
  enhanceUI: true
  writeTo: "body"
```

What could be happening here?, how can I pass parameters to render method?

Comment: Be aware of that `options[key] ||= val`. If you pass `enhanceUI: false` it will be overriden as `true`. If you don't want that, you can change it to `options[key] ?= val` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just being fooled by an asynchronous `console.log`. Your first `console.log` call is just grabbing a reference to `options` but by the time it tries to log it, you've already updated it. Try this instead:

```
render: (options = {}) ->
  console.log 'options'
  console.log _(options).clone()
  console.log 'options'
  options[key] ||= val for key, val of writeTo: 'body', enhanceUI: true
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EZc7N/

Comment: I'm not that sure if that is what's happening. Shouldn't he be getting `enhanceUI: true, writeTo: '.sandbox'` in the console because of its asynchronous behaviour?

Comment: @epidemian: That's a good point. It smells like the async problem, perhaps the code doesn't match what's really being done. Any ideas of what else it could be?

Comment: Nope, but as your answer has been accepted it probably was a `console.log` problem :) (maybe there was more code than what we see here and the `options` object was modified later on?).

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem. This [works as expected](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3arender%20%3D%20%28options%20%3D%20%7B%7D%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20console.log%20%27first%3A%27%2C%20JSON.stringify%20options%0A%20%20options%5Bkey%5D%20%7C%7C%3D%20val%20for%20key%2C%20val%20of%20writeTo%3A%20%27body%27%2C%20enhanceUI%3A%20true%0A%20%20console.log%20%27then%3A%27%2C%20JSON.stringify%20options%0A%0Arender%20writeTo%3A%20%27.sandbox%27):

```
render = (options = {}) ->
  console.log 'first:', JSON.stringify options
  options[key] ||= val for key, val of writeTo: 'body', enhanceUI: true
  console.log 'then:', JSON.stringify options

render writeTo: '.sandbox'
```

Output:

```
first: {"writeTo":".sandbox"}
then: {"writeTo":".sandbox","enhanceUI":true}
```

Notice that i'm logging the JSON stringification of the object to avoid logging the same object twice (as the object is the same, the debugging console would print the same values (its current state)).

Also, you maight be interested in [Underscore's `default`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) to fill default arguments:

```
render = (options = {}) ->
  _.defaults options, writeTo: 'body', enhanceUI: true
```